# Angular DI using injection token for model class

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, injection-tokens

I am trying to do something here, but not sure if it can be done.
I want to create a model class like this:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
    Element,
    Image,
} from '@situlive/situ-angular-components/contentful';

export class ImageColumn {
    title: string;
    backgroundImage: Image;
    backgroundImageAlignment: string;

    constructor(
        element: Element
    ) {
        this.title = element.fields.title;
        this.backgroundImageAlignment = element.fields.backgroundImageAlignment;
    }
}
```

This is so that in a component or service I can just do a `new ImageColumn(element)` and it will bind the properties for me.
Easy so far.

Now I have a complication :) I need to bind the the **backgroundImage**, which is done through a service. I updated the constructor to this:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
    ContentfulService,
    Element,
    Image,
} from '@situlive/situ-angular-components/contentful';

export class ImageColumn {
    title: string;
    backgroundImage: Image;
    backgroundImageAlignment: string;

    constructor(
        contentfulService: ContentfulService,
        element: Element
    ) {
        this.title = element.fields.title;
        this.backgroundImageAlignment = element.fields.backgroundImageAlignment;

        this.backgroundImage = this.contentfulService.createImage(
            element.fields.backgroundImage[0]
        );
    }
}
```

which is fine, but it causes an issue, because now anywhere where I use an **ImageColumn** I now have to pass in the **contentfulService**. I would really love to be able to pass the service without needing to supply it in the constructor.

I have done this before with services using **injection tokens**, so I figured I could do it here.
I created an injection token like this:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

import { ContentfulService } from '@situlive/situ-angular-components/contentful';

export const CONTENTFUL_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<ContentfulService>(
  'CONTENTFUL_SERVICE'
);
```

which I provided in my module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,

    AuthModule.forRoot(environment.auth0),
    ContentfulModule.forRoot(environment.contentful),
  ],
  declarations: [FooterComponent, HeaderComponent],
  exports: [FooterComponent, HeaderComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: BearerInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: CONTENTFUL_SERVICE,
      useClass: ContentfulService,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

So I figured I would be able to do this to my model:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
    ContentfulService,
    Element,
    Image,
} from '@situlive/situ-angular-components/contentful';

import { CONTENTFUL_SERVICE } from '../contentful-service.token';

export class ImageColumn {
    title: string;
    backgroundImage: Image;
    backgroundImageAlignment: string;

    constructor(
        @Inject(CONTENTFUL_SERVICE) private contentfulService: ContentfulService,
        element: Element
    ) {
        this.title = element.fields.title;
        this.backgroundImageAlignment = element.fields.backgroundImageAlignment;

        this.backgroundImage = this.contentfulService.createImage(
            element.fields.backgroundImage[0]
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is, now when i do a `new ImageColumn(element)` it complains that I need 2 arguments but only got 1.
Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it doesn't work that way because you didn't declare any **provider** for the `ImageColumn`. Declaring the provider would let the **injector** know how to obtain dependencies when you inject the `ImageColumn` as follows:

```js
constructor (imageColumn: ImageColumn) { }
```

but since you want to instantiate it *manually*, I'm not sure you can let Angular know how to automatically resolve the injection token.

What I think you can do instead is to provide the `Injector` when you instantiate `ImageColumn`.

#### foo.component.ts

```js
export class FooComponent {
  constructor (private injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit () {
    const imgColumn = new ImageColumn(element, this.injector)
  }
}
```

and then in your `ImageColumn`'s constructor you can inject anything that has a provider declared, including that service:

```js
class ImageColumn {
  constructor (private element: any, private injector: Injector) {
    this.contentfulService = this.injector.get(ContentfulService);

    /* ... */

    this.backgroundImage = this.contentfulService.createImage(
      element.fields.backgroundImage[0]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I will accept this as the answer; I knew you could do this, but in all honesty, it's probably better just injecting the service